# simple? jquery browser compatibility issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/RBD3K/6/

Works awesome in safari, however when i try in firefox the grey div stays hidden behind the green one.
Does anyone has an idea what could be the cause of this problem?

Comment: yes. outdated firefox :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`console.log` do not work in the firefox version you tested so its throwing exception on that line and animation is failing. Comment that line it works fine.